# Syntax Error:Creating An 2d List Filled With Zero

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

How Could I Initialize An 2D List Filled With Zeroes Without Any Additional Library/Module

here what is my attempt

```
table = [0 for i in range(amount + 1)[0 for j in range(len(coins))]]
```

it works in case of 1d list:Vector But Fails In Case Of 2d

> Code:
> `table = [0 for i in range(amount + 1)]`
> O/P:
> `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`
>
> Code:
> `table = [0 for i in range(amount + 1)[0 for j in range(len(coins))]]`
> O/P:
> `Syntax Error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the inner comprehension part in the wrong position. Try:

```py
rows, cols = 4, 5
table = [[0 for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]
print(table)
# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

First, `_` here is nothing strange; it is just a dummy name, which we don't care. We could name it `i` for example, and nothing changes.

`[... for _ in range(rows)]` makes a list with length `rows`, with the items given by `...`. Now `...` was `[0 for _ in range(cols)]`, i.e.,  a list of zeros with length `cols`. Therefore, the result is a list (having length `row`) of `[0, 0, ..., 0]`.

Comment: It worked but can you explain how?

Comment: @CodeBhiErrorBhi I've added some explanations.